# game of life "cells" not updating correctly

Tags: javascript

So i am trying to code conway's game of life in javaScript but something isn't working. If i but three cells in a row they should just flip directions but instead it makes a 2 by 2 square. I looked around and found that you need to wait to update position until the whole "board" is scanned. But i atleast think I'm already doing that. So I genuinely have no clue what is wrong.

I call the  uppdateGridValues function to run a generation

```js
function getCellValue(row, col) {
  try {
    return arry[row][col];
  } catch (e) {
    return 0;
  }
}

function countNeighbours(row, col) {
  let neighbours = 0;

  neighbours += getCellValue(parseInt(row - 1), parseInt(col - 1));
  neighbours += getCellValue(parseInt(row - 1), parseInt(col));
  neighbours += getCellValue(parseInt(row - 1), parseInt(col + 1));

  neighbours += getCellValue(parseInt(row), parseInt(col - 1));
  neighbours += getCellValue(parseInt(row), parseInt(col + 1));

  neighbours += getCellValue(parseInt(row + 1), parseInt(col - 1));
  neighbours += getCellValue(parseInt(row + 1), parseInt(col));
  neighbours += getCellValue(parseInt(row + 1), parseInt(col + 1));

  return neighbours;
}

function uppdateCell(i, j) {
  const total = countNeighbours(i, j);
  if (arry[i][j] === 0 && total == 3) {
    return 1;
  } else if (total > 4 || total < 3) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return arry[i][j];
  }
}

function uppdateGridValues() {
  for (var i = 0; i < cellsInRow; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < cellsInCollum; j++) {
      let newState = uppdateCell(i, j);
      arryOld[i][j] = newState;
    }
  }

  arry = arryOld;
  arryOld = arry;
}
```

Create Array

```
let arry = [];
let arryOld = [];

for(var i = 0; i < cellsInRow; i++){
    
    arry[i] = [];
    
    for(var j = 0; j < cellsInCollum; j++){
        
        arry[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

arryOld = arry;
```

I do sometimes get NaN when writing out the total variable in the uppdateCell function. I don't know why because i am suppose to return a 0 if the value passed to getCellValue from countNeighbours is outside the array size.

Comment: Accessing an nonexistent array element doesn't raise an exception, so you can't use `try` for that.

Comment: Why are you calling `parseInt` here: `parseInt(row - 1)`? `row-1` is an integer, you don't need to parse it.

Comment: Deleted my answer because there seems to be multiple problems. The main one I saw though:  `arry = arryOld;
 arryOld = arry;`
This is not swapping between two arrays. This is making both arrays point to the same object, which means you're modifying the same grid that you're reading from. This is a common error that messes with the classic patterns.

You need to incorporate a temporary variable to properly swap them:

`temp = arry;
arry = arryOld;
arryOld = temp;`
Now they remain as distinct objects instead of two variables pointing to the same object.

Comment: Also, remove the `arryOld = arry;` line from the creation code. That's also contributing to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `try/catch` to detect reading outside the array. Access outside the array just returns `undefined`, it doesn't raise an exception.

You can use `||` to return a default if the value isn't set (note that this works in this particular case because there are no other "falsey" values that are valid to return, it can't always be used like this).

```
function getCellValue(row, col) {
  return arry[row][col] || 0;
}
```

Another problem is that

```
arryOld = arry;
```

doesn't make a copy of the array, both variables refer to the same array. Use this to make a deep copy of the array.

```
arryOld = arry.map(row => [...row]);
```

Answer (score 1):

### My guess at the issue

I'm reading through, and I've found something which may be causing the error:
your calls of `parseInt()` in `countNeighbors()`.

From the [MDN JavaScript Docs on `parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> "The `parseInt()` function parses a string argument and returns an integer ... or `NaN`. (if the input is invalid in a few different ways)"

Basically, `parseInt()` is expecting string input and youre giving it integer input. I'd reccomend removing the calls to `parseInt()` from `countNeighbors()` like this:

```js
function countNeighbours(row, col) {
  let neighbours = 0;

  neighbours += getCellValue((row - 1), (col - 1));
  neighbours += getCellValue((row - 1), (col));
  neighbours += getCellValue((row - 1), (col + 1));

  neighbours += getCellValue((row), (col - 1));
  neighbours += getCellValue((row), (col + 1));

  neighbours += getCellValue((row + 1), (col - 1));
  neighbours += getCellValue((row + 1), (col));
  neighbours += getCellValue((row + 1), (col + 1));

  return neighbours;
}
```

### Some other suggestions

While I was reading thru this code, I thought of a few suggestions on things you might be able to do it. (These are totally optional tho! None of these things could be causing your code to break.)

1. `arry` as a global variable here works, but global variables make code harder to manage and understand. I would make this a local variable of a main function, and pass it into all of your other functions.
2. `arry` should be renamed to something more descriptive; possibly `gameboard` or `grid`.
3. `countNeighbors()` can be shortened and simplified using a nested for, similar to what you have in `updateGridValues()`. Here's an example of how that could be done:

```js
function countNeighbours(row, col) {
  let neighbourTotal = 0;
  for (let y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
    for (let x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
      neighbourTotal += getCellValue(row + y, col + x);
    }
  }
 
  return neighbourTotal;
}
```

Comment: Reading others' answers and responses, this issue is not the only issue here, and also likely isn't causing the error. Still, this issue could use fixing, so I'll keep the answer up.